# Minimizing geodesic in sufaces with boundary

Tags: riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds, surfaces, geodesic, manifolds-with-boundary

Let $(M, g)$ be a (Cauchy) complete Riemannian surface with boundary and fix a point $p \in M \setminus \partial M$. Is there a minimizing geodesic from $p$ to $\partial M$?
I believe this is true, but I am not used to working with geodesics in this context.

Comment: Yes, this is straightforward, assuming that $M$ is a connected complete metric space with respect to the Riemannian distance function. The proof is essentially the same as the existence of a minimal geodesic between two disjoint compact sets in a complete Riemannian manifold. Pick any smooth curve connecting the point $P$ to $\partial M$. The distance from $P$ to $\partial M$ has to be less than the length $\ell$ of this curve. The set $S$ of all points in $\partial M$ whose distance from $P$  is $\le \ell$ is compact. I'll let you finish the rest.

Comment: Eduardo Longa Is the boundary is closed?